# PHP- Hiding unused time stamp references

Tags: php

I have come across an issue I am not sure how to approach. I am comparing time now with a time in the future to get the difference in time or in this case, time remaining and that part works great. Here is the snippet which does that for reference to my issue.

```
  $current = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
  $expired = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', strtotime($expires));

  $dteStart = new DateTime($current); 
  $dteEnd   = new DateTime($expired);

  $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
```

Then in my HTML I insert the following...

```
echo $dteDiff->format("%ad %hh %im");
```

As stated this all works great with one exception. It produces unused time references. For example.

> Remaining: 0d 0h 30m

As you can see I don't need the day or hour to show because it is not used. Where I am stuck is since it is all one single variable to display the time I am not sure how to hide the unused characters that are not needed when they are showing 0.

Show how can I hide the ones that show 0 and if all three show 0 show the word Expired? Could this be wrapped in an isset() even though it there is multiple values in one single variable? Any suggestions?

-Thanks

Comment: Just use the UNIX values and /60 to get minutes and so on.

Comment: @Andreas I am sorry. I am not sure I am following you. I am able to display the time. I am needing to hide the time references when they are displaying 0. Sure I could remove it all together but I need the day and hour for instances when days and hours are shown.

Comment: See this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#96768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$i = $dteDiff->format(" %ad %hh %im");
$i = str_replace(" 0d","",$i);
if (strpos($i, 'd') == false) {
  $i = str_replace(" 0h","",$i);
  if (strpos($i, 'h') == false) {
    $i = str_replace(" 0m","",$i);
  }
}
$i = trim($i);
if ($i == "") {
  $i = "expired";
}
echo $i;
```

Comment: It just occured to me that this could delete H/M  if you get an exact time like 4d 0h 0m, so I updated it accourdingly

Comment: That might actually be what was wanted. I think it isn't quite clear from the question.

Comment: @Nosajimiki thanks for the update. The original answer you posted worked like a charm and what I was looking for. I did over look that little caveat so thanks for thinking about that.

Comment: @Nosajimiki another thing I am noticing now is if there is a 0 in the time I.E. 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 etc. it will remove the 0 from it so for example if the time is 40m it will just show it as 4 doesn't even show the m, just shows it as 4.

Comment: @Texan78 - I've changed it to add a leading space to the string, and then replace only values that have a leading space.  The Trim is to remove the leading space when you are done processing it.  See if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regular expression to replace any zero values.

```
echo preg_replace('/\b0[dhm] ?/', '', $dteDiff->format("%ad %hh %im")) ?: 'Expired';
```